# using 'loop' or 'for' with table data to pull each row data and use the pulled data for two parameters in gams

Tags: gams-math

I am new to GAMS and I have a table data which has 3 rows and 6 columns. I want to pull each row and use its data for two parameters(pull each row which has 6 element and use the first three elements for one parameter and the other three elements for the second parameter) using loop or for statement. i tried to use both of them but for the loop i received zero value for my parameter which is incorrect and for the for statement i received some errors. 
    this is my code for the first row which both 'loop' and 'for' are used (i used them separately  each time but for show what was my code i just wrote them together). 
Please help me.
Thanks

```
    scalars j;
    sets
    o /red,green,blue/
    p /b1,b2,b3,p1,p2,p3/
    k /1*3/;

    Table sup(*,*)
           b1 b2 b3 p1  p2  p3
    red    12 15 20 200 50  50
    green  16 17 0 150  50  0
    blue   13 18 0 100  50  0 ;

    parameters Bid_Red(k),Pmax_Red(k),t;

    *for statement***************
    for(j= 1 to 3,
    t=card(o)+j;
    Bid_Red(k)$( ord(k) = j )=sup('red',j);
    Pmax_Red(k)$( ord(k) = j )=sup('red',t);
    );

    *loop statement***************
     t=card(o);
    loop(k,
    Bid_Red(k)=sup('red',k);
    Pmax_Red(k)=sup('red',k+t);
    );
    display Bid_red, Pmax_Red
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the core features of GAMS is how it deals with set structures and indexing. I'd recommend looking at the excellent documentation, for example on set definition https://www.gams.com/latest/docs/UG_SetDefinition.html, to really get a feel for how to get the best out of it.

In your case, you can proceed as follows. `p` is a set. Create some subsets of it `p_` and `b_`, given by the syntax `subset_name(set_name)`.

```
sets    p_(p) / p1, p2, p3 /,
        b_(p) / b1, b2, b3 /;
```

Create parameters over appropriate dimensions (i.e. the full set), and define them over the subset you are interested in:

```
parameters       bid_red(o,p),pmax_red(o,p);

bid_red(o,b_)  = sup(o,b_);
pmax_red(o,p_) = sup(o,p_);
```

Then `display bid_red, pmax_red;` gives:

```
----     21 PARAMETER bid_red  

               b1          b2          b3

red        12.000      15.000      20.000
green      16.000      17.000
blue       13.000      18.000


----     21 PARAMETER pmax_red  

               p1          p2          p3

red       200.000      50.000      50.000
green     150.000      50.000
blue      100.000      50.000
```

If you do want to select individual rows, you can use e.g. `pmax_red('red',p_)` in your code. This is essentially just a special case of subsetting in which the subset is of size 1.